# How to read negative numbers as list or array in Python?

Tags: python, io

Here is what I have tried so far

```
with open('xy.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist = [line.rstrip()[1:19] for line in f]
    print alist[0]

with open('xy1.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist1 = [line.rstrip()[1:19] for line in f]
    print alist1[0]

with open('yx.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist = [line.rstrip()[1:19] for line in f]
    print alist[0]

with open('yx1.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist1 = [line.rstrip()[1:19] for line in f]
    print alist1[0]
```

When I run code

```
5.509014339324e+03
4.927809838950e+03
6.440208621086e+03
1.912637550671e+03
```

But yx.txt has negative numbers

```
>ZYXR //74
-6.440208621086e+03 -4.758666382870e+03 -3.995858566350e+03 -4.934315690511e+03 -5.049765912718e+03
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at 0. Python sequences are 0-indexed. By using `[1:19]`, you are probably cutting off the first character, which is `-`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved if you use the function split(). This will separate your line in "words", so whichever format do you had should be read correctly.

The result code will be:

```
with open('xy.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist = [line.split[0] for line in f]
    print alist[0]

with open('xy1.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist1 = [line.split[0] for line in f]
    print alist1[0]

with open('yx.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist = [line.split[0] for line in f]
    print alist[0]

with open('yx1.txt') as f:
    next(f, None)
    alist1 = [line.split[0] for line in f]
    print alist1[0]
```